# Convert piped file to json using jq and insert labels

Tags: json, object, jq

Given a couple of pipe delimited text files:

file 1:

`data1|data2|data3|data4`

file 2:

`label1|label2|label3|label4`

I'm looking to create json output like this:

`{ "label1": "data1", "label2": "data2", "label3": "data3", "label4": "data4" }`

I've gotten this far:

`jq -R -s 'rtrimstr("\n") | split("|") | to_entries | reduce .[] as $o ({}; .["field" + ($o.key+1|tostring)] |= $o.value )'`

...which just increments fieldx labels, and doesn't use a "label" file, which is my main objective.

`{ "field1": "data1", "field2": "data2", "field3": "data3", "field4": "data4" }`

I realize there are lots of ways to get  this done, but I'm hoping to stay with jq for my own learning experience.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Is it always mapped one to one, i.e. each data corresponds to one label?

Comment: Yes, thanks - one-to-one mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimalist "reduce-free" solution, here spread over multiple lines for clarity:

```
jq -Rn '
  [inputs|split("|")]
  | transpose
  | map({(.[0]): .[1]})
  | add' labels.psv data.psv
```

#### Multiple data lines

The following handles multiple data lines, and is a little more robust as well:

```
jq -nR '
  # From the web:
  def objectify($keys):
    [$keys, .] | transpose | map({(.[0]): .[1]}) | add;

  (input|split("|")) as $keys
  | inputs | split("|") | objectify($keys)
' labels.psv data.psv
```

Comment: Thanks, that does a nice job, although I neglected to mention my data file will potentially have more than one line.  This seems to stop after the first line, but I'll mark it as answered because you did answer my question as stated!  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks.  You did say one-to-one, but if you want to elaborate the question, I'll try to elaborate the answer.

Comment: Yep, silly of me - I was thinking 1-1 in terms of field-to-field, which I guess was probably inherently obvious.  But in a nutshell - the labels file will always be one row representative of potentially many rows of data - each label acting like a column header, for lack of a better description.  I've had more coffee so hopefully that makes sense :-).